# Design ES6: appropriate way to identify group of classes

Tags: javascript, class, es6-class

I have a group of classes, they share no properties. What i want to do is to check if arbitrary object is instance of any class in this group.
I could think of two approaches, first is to define a special signature property in every one of those classes like string for example and check for it in the arbitrary object, second approach is to inherit all classes from an empty class and check if this arbitrary object is `instanceof` the base class constructor, so is it ok to inherit from an empty class ? and Which one is more appropriate ? or there's a better approach ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about this "group"? What's your real world use case, what's the problem that is solved by identifying the instances?

Comment: it's a group of authentication classes. I have a function that takes instance of any authentication class as a parameter, and i want to throw exception if this parameter isn't instance of one of my authentication classes.

Comment: In the above comment i simplified the problem to a function that wants to check if its parameter is an instance class in this set, but i'm afraid that will change the problem a little bit, the original use case is another class that its constructor takes the authorization instance as a parameter. In the function case i could relay on the duck-typing thing but that doesn't apply on the class constructor since it won't throw an error unless i used the instance in the constructor's body

Comment: If the class doesn't use the instance anywhere, then why would the constructor take it as a parameter? Actually this sounds like a *perfect* use case for duck typing - check whether the argument has the methods that you want to call. (Which probably also means that the classes actually *do* share some method names etc, which would make inheritance suitable as well).

Comment: the delegator class actually uses the instance but not in the constructor body, it uses it in the methods, so if i relayed on duck-typing the exception would be thrown when i call the delegator's methods but i want it to be thrown when i create an instance from the delegator with invalid authorization class. As for sharing methods, they share only the names of the methods but not the behavior nor the code, and unfortunately javascript doesn't provide interface classes without Typescript

Comment: Duck typing doesn't mean that you have to call a method to see whether it exists or throws an exceptions. You can check for the existence right in the constructor.

Comment: I got what're you saying, but i think this approach is neither efficient nor generic. because you'll have to hardcode checks for all methods you are using in the delegator and they could be many! and if you made a change in any of the classes you'll have to change your condition in the delegator's constructor.

Comment: Yes, "*check for all methods you are using*" is exactly what duck typing means. No, there should not be many methods in your interface, and the interface should change rarely if ever so hardcoding is fine. No, you don't need to change the condition when any of the classes change. Only when the interface changes, you need to change everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should go with inheritance here, as it semantically and intuitively makes the most sense. You have a group of classes, and they belong to a common set, and even if they don't share concrete properties with that parent, they do share the abstract property that they 'belong' to that parent.

Multiple approaches work of course, but I think this is the one that represents the idea best.

Comment: No. Inheritance makes no sense for classes that don't share any properties.

Comment: I think it does make sense for this case, because even though the classes don't share properties, they do belong to a group. So you can say they belong to this abstract class of Authorizers, and the way you express 'belonging' in OOP is through inheritance. Even though they don't inherit actual properties, they do inherit a common type. That's my thought process anyway

Comment: The major problem with inheritance is that it's linear. We can group classes rather arbitrarily by different abstractions, and have classes that "belong" to multiple groups. I'm not saying that inheritance can't work when it's appropriate, but we should not apply it as a generic solution for this problem - and the OP stating that they don't share any properties doesn't sound like they're subtypes of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't use classes but it should be the same with constructor functions since JS classes are just syntactical sugar. So,

```js
function Maker(n){
  this.number = n;
}

Maker.prototype.getConstructorName = function(){
                                       return this.constructor.name;
                                     };

var obj1 = new Maker(10);
console.log(obj1.getConstructorName());
```

Comment: Don't use `.name` to identify anything.

Comment: Why should he not use classes when it's the same and `class` syntax makes our code sweeter?

Comment: @Bergi It's not sufficient to say "Don't use `.name` to identify anything" please elaborate me why shouldn't I use it. Really no sarcasm here.. I will be grateful to know why should i go another way to do this task. As per classes, although i know the ES6 classes pretty well, since I don't code in PHP, Phyton, C, C++, C#, Java, Swift i haven't got a class type mindset. So to me constructor functions are sweet enough. I didn't say he should not use them.

Comment: @Redu I don't think that you got my question! your approach identifies only single class by its name, but i want to check if this object is instance of any class in a certain classes set

Comment: @Redu The `.name` property of functions is mostly useful for debugging. It is not supported in many older browsers (notably IE), and it can get destroyed by minifiers or similar tooling. Better test for identity of the constructor if you really need to (i.e. `obj1.constructor == Maker`). Also, name collisions can occur - not sure whether you meant to rely on them to identify a class as one of a certain group by giving them all the same name.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks.. right i also dug a little and there are some problems here like `var Maker = function(n){ this.number  = n; this.Maker1  = function(m){ this.number = m; }; }, obj1 = new Maker(1); obj2 = new obj1.Maker1(2); console.log(obj1.constructor.name); console.log(obj2.constructor.name);`